# Is it possible to use Stripe Connect with Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments

Has anybody successfully integrated Stripe Connect and Meteor.js ? I have used Stripe Checkout to collect payments from a buyer, through a Meteor package, but I am now investigating building a marketplace where buyers and sellers transact with each other directly.

I haven't found any Stripe connect packages for Meteor. I would also be willing to pay anybody who could successfully set up Stripe Connect and Meteor.js.

Comment: Meteor.js is usually a client-side framework so it shouldn't have much of an impact on your usage of Stripe Connect. I'd recommend reading Stripe's thorough quickstart on Connect first here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide and then you can adapt this to your own integration/needs.

Comment: This is the best thing with Meteor, you don't need meteor packages to do everything. It is just HTML and JS.

Comment: @Onwego which frontend do you use in your Meteor project (Blaze, React, Vue etc.)?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I'm using Blaze but will switch to React or Vue if that makes stripe connect integration easier.

Comment: @koopajah unfortunately my knowledge of javascript is still in the beginner stages so I wouldn't be able to implement any package that doesn't have a tutorial. i've built apps before but that was based on reading official meteor tutorials and documentation. I'm sure you would need to be developing in node.js for a few years if not almost a decade to understand how to adapt stripe for node to meteor and I'm just not there yet. any more specific insights would be helpful.